# How to monitor database updates from application?

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, database, odbc

I work with SQL Server database with ODBC, C++. I want to detect modifications in some tables of the database: another application inserts or updates rows and I have to detect all these modifications. It does not have to be the immediate trigger, it is acceptable to use polling to periodically check database tables for modifications.

Below is the way I think this can be done, and need your opinions whether this is the standard/right way of doing this, or any better approaches exist.

What I've thought of is this: I add triggers in SQL Server, which, on any modification, will insert the identifiers of modified/added rows into special table, which I will check periodically from my application. Suppose there are 3 tables: Customers, Products, Services. i will make three additional tables: Change_Customers, Change_Products, Change_Services, and will insert the identifiers of modified rows of the respective tables. Then I will read these Change_* tables from my application periodically and delete processed records.

Now if you agree that above solution is right, I have another question: Is it better to have separate Change_* tables for each of my tables I wish to monitor, or is it better to have one fat Changes table which will contain the changes from all tables.

Comment: If you have separate tables, you can have foreign keys to the actual table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175110.aspx) is the technology designed to do *exactly* what you're describing. You can leverage Query Notifications from managed clients via the well known [SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) class, but there are native Ole DB and ODBC ways too. See [Working with Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx), the paragraphs about `SSPROP_QP_NOTIFICATION_MSGTEXT` (OleDB) and  `SQL_SOPT_SS_QUERYNOTIFICATION_MSGTEXT` (ODBC). See [The Mysterious Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/) for an explanation how Query Notifications work.

This is the only polling-free solution that work with any kind of updates. Triggers and polling for changes has severe scalability and performance issues. Change Data Capture and Change Tracking are really covering a different topic (synchronizing datasets for occasionally connected devices, eg. Sync Framework).

Answer (score 1):

Change Data Capture(CDC)--http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645937.aspx

First you will need to enable CDC in database
::
USE db_name
GO
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_db
GO

Enable CDC on table then 
:: sys.sp_cdc_enable_table

Then you can query changes

Answer (score 0):

- If your version of Sql Server is 2005 - you may use [Notification Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170337%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)
- If your Sql Server is 2008+ - there is most preferrable way to use triggers and log changes to log tables and periodically poll these tables from application to see the changes

Comment: Even if the database server is currently SQL 2005 I wouldn't recommend using Notification Services.  NS was deprecated and building anything today that is dependent upon would prevent you from upgrading your database server.