# Update client-PCs with each others activities (insert, update, delete)

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, client-server

I am developing a Client-Server application using C# .NET Winforms with SQL Server 2008. The client pc's connect to the database server via the LAN.

The task I want to achieve is when an insert (or update or delete) is performed on one client-PC, all other clients must get that update in real-time.

I am currently using timers, so that each client queries the database every 15 seconds then refreshes the gridviews, combo boxes and list boxes. But this makes the application slow and bulky to use.

What is the correct method to use in such scenario. What are such operations called (correct terminology)? Should I use windows services? or same application with background threads ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to monitor database updates from application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092398/how-to-monitor-database-updates-from-application)

Comment: I think you want to look into Query Notifications. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx, http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, its Windows, so it cannot ever be realtime.

The solutions that – Igby Largeman suggests is well possible. It does have the disadvantage that it can cause very heavvy network traffic, because every time something changes in the database, it is broadcasted to all the clients.

You also have to consider the possibility that something clogs ub the communication between the server and one or more clients, so realtime is out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

that's tricky!
If you really want a user with a grid open on PCA to see data inserted on a PCB without performing any action, you will need a timer to refresh the grid. But I dont think this is a good aproach, you can easily overload the system.

The good practice here is display only the data due to be manipulated. So for example, lets say you want to alter a client's name. You build a search form with a grid where the user can inform search parameters (to filter the data) and once the client is found and altered, you perform another search to the DB to get and display the new data.

But lets say another user had the same grid open showing the client before you perform the alteration. It is showing the old value, but once it clicks on it to see the details, you'll perform a search to the DB to get the new data so that would be ok.